# Need the best way to find object

Tags: scala, collections

Everyone!

I have 3 classes:

```
case class Foo(id: String, bars: Option[List[Bar]])
case class Bar(id: String, buzzes: Option[List[Buz]])
case class Buz(id: String, name: String)
```

And the collection:

```
val col = Option[List[Foo]]
```

I need to get:

```
val search: String = "find me"
val (x: Option[Foo], y: Option[Bar], z: Option[Buz]) = where buz.name == search ???
```

Help please :)

**upd:**
i have the json

```
{
  "foos": [{
      "id": "...",
      "bars": [{
          "id": "...",
          "buzzes": [{
               "id": "...",
               "name": "find me"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

and the name in current context will be unique.

my first thought was - transform collection into list of tuples - like this:

```
{
  (foo)(bar)(buz),
  (foo)(bar)(buz),
  (foo)(bar)(buz)
}
```

and filter by buz with name == search

But,i don`t know how to :)

Comment: What if multiple `Buz` elements have the target `name` value?  Why `Option` each of the tuple members?  Wouldn't it make more sense to have `Option[(Foo,Bar,Buz)]`? No single member of the tuple could be `None` without them all being `None`.

Comment: added some explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big problem here is that after digging down far enough to find what you're looking for, the result type is going to reflect that morass of types: `Option[List[Option[List...etc`.

It's going to be easier (not necessarily better) to save off the find as a side effect.

```
val bz1 = Buz("bz1", "blah")
val bz2 = Buz("bz2", "target")
val bz3 = Buz("bz3", "bliss")

val br1 = Bar("br1", Option(List(bz1,bz3)))
val br2 = Bar("br2", None)
val br3 = Bar("br3", Option(List(bz1,bz2)))

val fo1 = Foo("fo1", Option(List(br1,br2)))
val fo2 = Foo("fo2", None)
val fo3 = Foo("fo3", Option(List(br2,br3)))

val col: Option[List[Foo]] = Option(List(fo1,fo2,fo3))

import collection.mutable.MutableList
val res:MutableList[(String,String,String)] = MutableList()

col.foreach(_.foreach(f => 
  f.bars.foreach(_.foreach(br =>
    br.buzzes.foreach(_.collect{
      case bz if bz.name == "target" => res.+=((f.id,br.id,bz.id))})))))

res   // res: MutableList[(String, String, String)] = MutableList((fo3,br3,bz2))
```